# How to pass values between .aspx form and .ashx handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, ashx

I want to draw image, based on user input (width, height, etc...)

I have my form in .aspx page, but i'm drawing image using ashx handler.

I've got a code that draws image, but only from pre-assigned values.

Now what i want to do is get values from my .aspx form

**.aspx**

```
<span>Width</span>
<asp:TextBox ID="input_width" Width="125" Text="600" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox><br/>
<span>Height</span>
<asp:TextBox ID="input_height" Width="125" Text="400" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

**.ashx.cs**

```
int width = 600;
int height = 400;

Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height);

Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage((Image)bmp);
g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, 0f, 0f, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
bmp.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);

byte[] bajt = ms.ToArray();

context.Response.ContentType = "image/png";
context.Response.BinaryWrite(bajt);
context.Response.Flush();
```

**Already tried this**

```
string _width = context.Request.QueryString.Get("input_width.Text");

        int __width = Convert.ToInt32(_width);
```

But the value seems to be null

**Some1 please help me?**

**Thank you!**

**UPDATE**

```
<a href="ImageGen.ashx">Press here</a><br />
        <img src="ImageGen.ashx" width="600" height="400"/>
```

Comment: Show where you are using the query param.

Comment: it's inside "public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)" @mybirthname

Comment: I mean in the aspx where you are calling the ashx.

Comment: @mybirthname please see update. is this ok, or do you need more info?

Comment: @fokz8 `src` attribute of your image tag has no query string parameters. It should be `Imagegen.ashx?param1=value1&param2=value2`

Comment: can you show example in code. and how to retrieve param1 in ashx? thanks @AksheyBhat

Comment: `string _param1= context.Request.QueryString.Get("param1");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not posting (or getting) from your .aspx page to your .ashx handler, as that is not how it works. This is why `context.Request.QueryString.Get("input_width.Text")` does not work. Also there is no need for ".Text", just "input_width".

You need to append the parameters to your call to the ashx:

```
<img src="ImageGen.ashx?w=<%= input_width.Text %>&h=<%= input_height.Text %>" width="600" height="400"/>
```

and in your handler

```
string _width = context.Request.QueryString["w"];
int __width = Convert.ToInt32(_width);
```

Comment: i just realized it only gets width that is set as value - Text="600". If i manually change it on my web form to 400, it still says 600 when i debug it ...any idea?

Comment: By setting `Text="600"` that is always going to be the value. Set a default value in the OnPageLoad event inside a `if(!isPostBack)` check.

Comment: yep you're right!. thank you!. one last question...somehow i can't pass background and text color to ashx if in hex format...string is empty when i run debug...no idea why? and if i paste in # later in ashx, it gives me "Color cannot accept # value"